# Vert.x EventBus to communicate between two different application in Quarkus?

Tags: message-queue, quarkus, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

Can we use Vert.x EventBus to publish message to one application and from another independent application to consume it

I've tested publishing to EventBus and consuming in one application, where it works flawlessly, but when I tried to publish messages to EventBus and have another application consume them, it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure about eventbus, but you can give a look at https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-reactive-messaging-http/dev/index.html; in few words this extension uses http endpoint (all is configurable) to send messages between services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the Vert.x event bus in a distributed manner, you need:

1. to put a Vert.x cluster manager on your classpath (I would recommend the Hazelcast one to start) - See https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-hazelcast/java/
2. Enable the clustered mode of Vert.x using: `quarkus.vertx.cluster.clustered=true` (in your application.properties file)

Instead of the second step, you can use https://quarkus.io/guides/vertx-reference#customizing-the-vert-x-configuration to customize the Vert.x configuration.

Note that the clustered event bus is not supported in native mode.